# ADO adTinyInt vs adUnsignedTinyInt with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ado

I am wondering what is the difference (in practical terms) between ADO data types `adTinyInt` and `adUnsigned`.

In the database (MS SQL Server) the column I am interacting with is of data

**So, for creating ADO parameters for a SQL Server `TINYINT` column, should I use `adTinyInt` or `adUnsigned`, and why?**

e.g. My aim is to support the range of values 0-255 which the SQL Server TINYINT supports. So I want to know which of those two ADO types best achieves that.

I read the definitions of each ADO data type on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675318(v=vs.85).aspx):

- adTinyInt (16) Indicates a one-byte signed integer (DBTYPE_I1).
- adUnsignedTinyInt (17) Indicates a one-byte unsigned integer (DBTYPE_UI1).

If the MS SQL data type TINYINT only holds values from 1 to 255, wouldn't the best choice be `adUnsignedTinyInt` (as is shown on the [W3 Schools ADO data type mapping matrix](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/ado_datatypes.asp))?

It seems like both are 1 byte in size so perhaps it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `adUnsignedTinyInt` because `adTinyInt` can have negative values that will are not allowed in SQL Server for `tinyint`, therefore you SQL call may fail

Your link (http://www.w3schools.com/asp/ado_datatypes.asp) does not mention `adTinyInt` for this reason

Comment: sql server should limit itself to store this negative value as a simple byte, when you get the same value you have to know that is signed and so you treat it as a signed byte (adTinyInt).

Comment: @CiroCorvino: suggest it here connect.microsoft.com because SQL Server stores only 0-255, unsigned currently, and has done for 20+ years

Comment: yes, but signed values are simply bytes with the most left bit at 1

Comment: +25 decimal is 00011001, -25 is 11100111 (-128+64+32+4+2+1). This disproves you statement. And -1 is all ones. "Two's complement" not "signed magnitude"

Comment: if the signed value is 25 in the tinyint column will be stored 00011001, else if the value is -25 in the col will be stored 11100111. The programmer must to know if the tinyint column contain a signed or unsigned value, and so treat it of conseguence. With the right type.

Comment: maybe the designer of Sql Server didn't want down to a such level of detail of 0-255 range values.. and so they preferred leave it without manage signed and unsigned cases considering that this cases are minority and so leaving to the programmer the burden to manage this cases. Instead Ado designer did..

Comment: This all makes sense. `adUnsignedTinyInt` it is.

Comment: @robarwebservices yes but what was your original question?

Comment: Updated the question to be more clear in what I wanted to support. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @robarwebservices I think that your behaviour it isn't honest and honourable, man.. first you ask for a thing and then.. you change idea.. you can do it, sure.. but you don't know what is to be a coherent person who respects others and their time

Comment: @CiroCorvino - I meant no disrespect, and I tried to be clear in phrasing my question. I also showed that I researched the topic in question. I added clarification to the question for the benefit of others who might see this down the line, but I don't think I changed the actual question in any material way.  All along the question said I was dealing with a SQL Server TINYINT column, and asked what ADO type is best suited to dealing with that. Not sure why that warrants a down-vote.

Comment: @robarwebservices I'm sorry but you have initially asked for the difference between adTinyInt and adUnsignedTinyInt ADO types and why one should use one of them.. in a such way you should have taken the right choice among them.. the specification row you added after, simply only need to justify your choice.. and that it isn't a beautyful behaviour.. my answer respond rightly to your original question and I don't know why you have chosen a question more poor.. but I don't care

Comment: My question, in bold font face, is, and always has been: "So, for creating ADO parameters for a SQL Server TINYINT column, should I use adTinyInt or adUnsigned, and why?"

Comment: @robarwebservices the answer I gave you is: depends on what is your intention. That it is also the explanation for why there are two types in ADO for manage the same type in Sql Server. That is your real orginal question (see also your question's title).

Answer (score -1):

If you want to store values from `-128` to `127`, then use `adTinyInt` to pass and retrieve these values to/from the relative Sql Server `TINYINT` column.

Instead pass an `adUnsignedTinyInt` parameter type for store values in the range `0-255`.

Comment: SQL Server tinyint only supports 0-255 so you can't use adTinyInt reliably. adTinyInt is not an option

Comment: @Shawn yes, but signed values are simply bytes with the most left bit at 1, so they fall always in the range 0-255, it is their meaning to be different based on the value of the most left bit

Comment: My aim is to support the range of values 0-255 which the SQL Server TINYINT supports. So I guess whatever ADO type achieves that is the one I want.

Comment: @robarwebservices ok then you have to use adUnsignedTinyInt ADO type, as said in the answer. Remeber that your original request was: "what is the difference  between ADO data types adTinyInt and adUnsigned"..